# lstatSync() Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm definitely new to Node.js, and I'm trying to recursively get all the files in a folder dropped, but when using lstatSync(path), it keeps returning undefined. If you're curious why this looks weird and I'm using Materialize and JSX, it's because this is part of an Electron app.

The error reads:

Uncaught TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined at lstatSync

```
const sendFiles = (files) => {
            for (let file of files) {
                const stat = fs.lstatSync(file.path);

                // if file is a folder, recursively check each file in the nested folders
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    // rename for clarity
                    let files = fs.readdirSync(file.path);
                    sendFiles(files);
                } else {
                    // notify user about incompatible file types
                    if (
                        file.path.split(".").pop() !== "js" &&
                        file.path.split(".").pop() !== "css" &&
                        file.path.split(".").pop() !== "html" &&
                        file.path.split(".").pop() !== "svg"
                    ) {
                        //materialize toast
                        M.toast({
                            html: `"${file.path
                                .split("/")
                                .pop()}" could not be minified due to incompatible file type.`,
                        });
                    } else {
                        //send to main process for minification
                        ipcRenderer.send("file:add", file.path);
                        setRedir(<Redirect to="/list" />);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

This is where the function is called:

```
document.ondrop = (e) => {
            sendFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
            e.preventDefault();
        };
```

Is there any prevalent reason why this issue arises? As I said, I'm new to Node, so something may just be completely going over my head here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `e.dataTransfer.files` returns an array of `file` objects with their full filename in the `path` property, but `fs.readdirSync` returns an array of just filenames without their path.

So the first time you called the `sendFiles(files)` function, each `file` of `files` had a `path` property.

But as soon as it hit a folder and tried to call itself recursively, it passed a list of filenames without paths.  Since it expected file objects, not simple names, it complained that `file.path` was `undefined`.

Here is a modified function that recursively logs the full filename of all files dragged-and-dropped, including all files inside dragged-and-dropped folders:

```js
function sendFiles(files) {
  for (let file of files) {
    file = file.path || file;
    let folder;
    if (fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
      let folder = file;
      let files = fs.readdirSync(folder).map(fileName => {
        return path.join(folder, fileName)
      });
      sendFiles(files);
    } else {
      console.log(file); // full filename with path
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I switch lstatSync to use file.name instead of file.path, it gives me an ENOENT error because the raw file name doesn't suffice as a directory path.

Comment: My mistake.  I edited my answer with the correct solution.

Comment: This definitely got me closer. After implementing the very helpful solution you gave, I'm now overloading the call stack since there isn't a base case. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: You're getting a `maximum call stack size exceeded` error?

Comment: Yep, currently looking for a workaround. Interestingly enough, this still happens even if it's just a folder with three files in it.

Comment: My test handles all the files and folders I've thrown at it.  My `HTML` is `<input type='file' id='file' multiple='true'>` and the corresponding JavaScript is `document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('drop', e => { e.preventDefault(); sendFiles(e.dataTransfer.files); }, false);`.

Comment: Awesome, I actually just got it. Fixed an error in another place that was throwing it, but thanks so much!!